# Python Sort Counter

Tags: python, sorting, counter

I cannot get my counter to sort/displayed properly

My code is

```
with open('nonweb') as f:
    for i in f:
            entry.append(i.strip())
    counter=Counter(entry)
print counter 

for z in counter:
        print '%s : %d' % (z, counter[z])
```

counter is

```
Counter({'192.168.1.45 UDP 137': 2262, '192.168.1.85 UDP 137': 2262, '192.119.43.56 UDP 53': 78, '192.119.39.68 UDP 53': 78, '192.168.92.223 UDP 10111': 78, '192.168.1.13 UDP 137': 72, '192.167.80.106 TCP 8087': 48, '192.168.1.127 UDP 8083': 48, '192.168.1.129 UDP 8083': 44, '192.218.30.124 UDP 53': 32, '192.77.58.44 TCP 5282': 24, '192.168.1.13 UDP 138': 18, '192.168.1.69 UDP 138': 14, '192.168.1.85 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.57 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.33 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.45 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.92 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.97 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.79 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.60 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.32 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.18 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.58 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.95 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.19 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.143 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.138 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.99 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.139 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.96 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.140 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.137 UDP 138': 10, '192.168.1.59 UDP 138': 10, '192.171.70.154 UDP 53': 6, '216.163.251.236 TCP 42590': 2, '192.168.1.140 TCP 56230': 2})
```

but when i try to display it in a presentable format, it does not print in the same order as the counter list. ( preferably no semi:colon)

```
192.168.1.45 UDP 137 : 2262
192.168.1.85 UDP 137 : 2262
192.168.1.85 UDP 138 : 10
192.168.1.57 UDP 138 : 10
192.168.1.33 UDP 138 : 10
192.168.1.45 UDP 138 : 10
192.168.1.92 UDP 138 : 10
192.168.1.129 UDP 8083 : 44
192.168.1.97 UDP 138 : 10
192.168.1.13 UDP 137 : 72
192.168.1.79 UDP 138 : 10
```

Comment: Counter depends on dict which depends on unsorted hashtable.

Comment: What you see in the Counter's `repr` is the counter's internal dictionary, which is not ordered. If you want the contents in sorted order, try `Counter.most_common`

Comment: What is the order you expect? First appeared, max occurrences, min occurrences, key?

Comment: max to min 2262, 2262, 72,44, 10 , 10 , 10, 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Counter` is implemented as a dictionary it doesn't really have a sense of order. If you want to manually iterate over its elements by order you will need to create such order:

```
# reverse=True to get descending order
for k, v in sorted(counter_obj.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```

Or simply iterate over the list of tuples returned by the `most_common` method as suggested by @tobias_k in the comments:

```
for k, v in c.most_common():
    print(k, v)
```

Interesting to note that `most_common` is implemented in almost the exact way:

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
        '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
        common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

        >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
        [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

        '''
        # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
        if n is None:
            return sorted(self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: Or just `Counter.most_common`? Can also take a parameter, e.g. `most_common(10)` for top-ten elements.

Comment: @tobias_k indeed, totally forgot about `most_common` returning ordered list of tuples. thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `counter.most_common()`:

```
for k,v in c.most_common():
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have in your Counter object is a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).
The order is not random but:

> Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

You could solve this with the use of an [orderddict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted.